# Assigning a vector to a struct's vector field

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm not sure why this works:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Pwm_Info tf_info;
    tf_info = get_pwm_info(library_data, motif_name);
}
```

Gen.cpp

```
        struct Pwm_Info {
    std::string motif_name;
    int width;
    std::vector < double > pwm;
    Pwm_Info(): motif_name(0),
    width(0),
    pwm(0) {}
}
TF_info;

Pwm_Info get_pwm_info(std::string library_data, std::string motif_name) {
    std::vector < double > double_list;
    strtk::parse(pwm_block, " \n\r", double_list);
    std::cout << double_list.size() << std::endl;

    Pwm_Info TF_info;

    TF_info.motif_name = motif_name;
    TF_info.width = n_width;

    std::vector < double > * pointer;
    std::vector < double > * pointer2;

    pointer = & TF_info.pwm;
    pointer2 = & double_list; * pointer = * pointer2;
    std::cout << TF_info.pwm[1] << std::endl;
    TF_info.pwm = double_list;
    return TF_info;
}
```

Previously, I removed the pointers to TF_info and double list, and just had the line:

```
  TF_info.pwm = double_list;
```

... which resulted in a SegFault.
What is the point of creating and assigning the pointers (pointer and pointer2) to each other?

Comment: Could you present a simple example demontsrating the problem without all your library_data, motif_name, Pwm_Info, TF_info and so on. Are you able to understand that it is defficult to read such a code?!

Comment: Have you kept the printing line before? Your proposed modification is actually totally legit.

Comment: Well if `std::cout << TF_info.pwm[1] << std::endl;` was before `TF_info.pwm = double_list;` and the pointer parts haven't been there then of course it won't work (original length of `TF_info.pwm`: `0`.

Comment: @Nabla, You are completely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pointer = &TF_info.pwm;
pointer2 = &double_list;
*pointer = *pointer2;
```

and

```
TF_info.pwm = double_list;
```

are totally equivalent!

---

The only line which could possibily cause a segfault is:

```
std::cout << TF_info.pwm[1] << std::endl;
```